# Show images grouped by their FK id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by

I have the following setup so far using Rails 4

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fixtures
  has_one :gallery
  has_many :gallery_images, :through => :gallery
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :gallery_images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery_images, allow_destroy: :true
end

class GalleryImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
end
```

With my db setup like so

```
 create_table "galleries", force: true do |t|
   t.integer  "tournament_id"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
 end

 create_table "gallery_images", force: true do |t|
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.string   "photo_file_name"
   t.string   "photo_content_type"
   t.integer  "photo_file_size"
   t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
   t.integer  "gallery_id"
 end

 create_table "tournaments", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.date     "tourn_date"
   t.string   "tourn_location"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I am trying to get a gallery and all its images into an object so that i can iterate through all the gallery_images by each tournament

```
<div id="verticalTab">
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
      <li><%= t.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <div class="resp-tabs-container">
  <div>    
  <% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
  <div class="clear"></div>
    <% g.gallery_images.each do |i| %>
      <ul class="team-gallery"> 
          <li><%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:gallery_image)) %></li>
        <% end %>  
      </ul>
    <% end %>
```

Controller

```
 def index
   @tournaments = Tournament.all
 end
```

Im a little unsure on how to group gallery_images by its tournament

Any pointers appreciated

Comment: in tournament model why not do has_many :gallery_images, :through => :gallery  You don't specify a rails version so your hash structure might look slightly different

Comment: why `@tournament.gallery.gallery_images` won't work?..

Comment: @user3334690 would i need to change any of my db structure with your suggestion?

Comment: @Richlewis - Nope, it will jjust work. However this most likely won't help you much (as it will do the same what you can do currently with `@tournament.gallery.gallery_images`. My question is: `@tournament.each` - is `@tournament` a collection? If so, could you show how you are getting this collection?

Comment: @user3334690 Ive updated the question with my controller

Comment: @Richlewis - I'm getting confused. Why do you want to group your gallery models by tournament whan each tornamnet has at most one gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this for your tournament model

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fixtures
  has_one :gallery
  has_many :gallery_images, through: :gallery
end
```

then in your view you could do something like

```
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
      <li><%= t.name %></li>
      <% t.gallery_images.each do |img| %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

or alternatively you could do something like this as roman.brodetski commented which would not require you to modify your model

```
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
      <li><%= t.name %></li>
      <% t.gallery.gallery_images.each do |img| %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

(note that your controller variable name @tournaments didn't agree with the one you were referencing in the view and would have been nil as a result)

One other thing to note is that your models Tournament and Gallery are one to one and I think what you may want given your question is that Tournament and Gallery be a one to many relationship, in which case your Tournament model should look like

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fixtures
  has_many :galleries
end
```

in which case you could have your view do something like

```
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
      <li><%= t.name %></li>
      <% t.galleries.map{|a| a.gallery_images}.flatten.each do |img| %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Comment: This will introduce N+1 problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helps to a point as you have helped me realise what association i need, i need to work on my layout now

Comment: @BroiSatse what do you mean?

Comment: @user3334690 - Number of db queries is dependent on a number of tournaments in a db. This is usually a serious problem and will have a major impact on a website performance. This is pretty ease to fix with correct `includes` statement in the controller, whcih should be a part of this solution. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse yes, I see your point now, that's usually the last thing I do, since things are likely to change dramatically until I'm done with a project... so I just didn't think about it